# Could someone explain this? (movement not working correctly)

Tags: java, libgdx

I added a thing to my game, so that when you press space you'll get a small speed boost. However, it only works correctly when you use the WASD keys. If you press the up and left or down and right arrowkeys, the boost won't work, but otherwise it does. Can anyone explain why it does that?

Here's the code:

```
    boostTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    if(boostTimer > 3){
    snailBoost = 0;
    boostTimer = 0;
    }

    //movement
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) && snailBoost < 20){
            snailBoost++;
            snail.getBounds().x -= (snailSpeed + 100) * delta;
        }

        //flips the sprite
        snail.getSprite().setFlip(false, true);
        snail.getBounds().x -= snailSpeed * delta;

        //handles what happens when you go outside the game world
        if(snail.getBounds().x < -100)snail.getBounds().x = 1920;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) && snailBoost < 20){
            snailBoost++;
            snail.getBounds().x += (snailSpeed + 100) * delta;
        }

        snail.getSprite().setFlip(true, true);
        snail.getBounds().x += snailSpeed * delta;

        if(snail.getBounds().x > 2020)snail.getBounds().x = -100;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) && snailBoost < 20){
            snailBoost++;
            snail.getBounds().y -= (snailSpeed + 100) * delta;
        }

        snail.getBounds().y -= snailSpeed * delta;

        if(snail.getBounds().y < -100)snail.getBounds().y = 1080;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) && snailBoost < 20){
            snailBoost++;
            snail.getBounds().y += (snailSpeed + 100) * delta;
        }

        snail.getBounds().y += snailSpeed * delta;

        if(snail.getBounds().y > 1080)snail.getBounds().y = -100;
    }
```

Sorry for messy code. :P 
Still new to game development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheap keyboards share the control lines of the keys, so some key combinations won't register correctly and trying to press more than 3-4 keys at once will result in nothing happening.

Either buy a more expensive keyboard, or choose keys so they work (such as the famous WASD you've already noticed works). Nothing to do with code.